# How resolve xamarin error ConnectFailure?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, httpwebrequest

I am sending a data by POST but I get an error in the line of code **Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream ();** it's my first time using Xamarin, basically I am trying to load the listview with data from a table.
In Postman work fine the link of the API I can see the data when sent from API.

Code:

```html
private async void btnbuscar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                string url = "http://localhost/XXX/XX";
                string juser = txtdesc.Text;
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                req.KeepAlive = true;
                req.Method = "POST";
                string Data = "desc=" + juser;
                byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data);
                
                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";//
                req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
                Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();//When I make debug here mark error.
                requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
                requestStream.Close();

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                
                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var msjdes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootListObject>>(responseText);
                    listparts.ItemsSource = msjdes;
                }
                else
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Mensaje", "", "");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error",ex.Message,"OK");
            }
            
        }
```

Erro:
[image]

Comment: please do not use "localhost".  Use the IP or FQDN of the server.

Comment: @Jason I'am using XAMMP and my API are on the folder htdocs, not upload on the server yet.

Comment: I change to 127.1.1.0 and it say the same error.

Comment: That is the loop backaddress, not the actual IP of the server.  Whatever machine is running your services is the “server”

Comment: okay I understand and saw the IP of mi computer using ipconfig cmd command and this IP put on the localhost and work.

Comment: Now the problem is when i try add the list deserialized to the listpart named object, the app not make nothing and just it closed.

Comment: OK, then debug it.  Which line causes the crash?  Have you tried handling any exception handling (try/catch) to your code to catch the exception?  What is the response you are getting in `responseText`?

Comment: Contains a Json Array deserialized. example [{"data":"info","data2":"info"},{"data":"info","data2":"info"},{"data":"info","data2":"info"}] the error is here listparts.ItemsSource = msjdes; it's the response of return of petition POST

Comment: Is the data being deserialized correctly?  What is the exception causing the crash?